# Django Class Based View finding templates

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to find in this views.py where the Class MovieList references the templates.

```
import datetime, calendar

from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
from movies.models import Movie, Show
from common.views import StatsDetailView
from common.models import Category, HotItem
from directory.models import Venue
import tasks


def _get_movie_dates():
    ###
    # Return list of dates for all future dates with movies showing
    ###

    return Movie.objects.filter(shows__starts__gte=datetime.date.today()).values_list('shows__starts', flat=True).order_by('shows__starts').distinct()

def _get_now_showing():
    ###
    # Return list of movies for now showing
    ###

    return Movie.objects.filter(shows__starts__gte=datetime.date.today()).order_by('name').distinct()

class MovieList(ListView):
    model = Movie
    paginate_by = 20
    context_object_name = 'movies'
    category = None
    venue = None
    date = None
    slug_level = ""

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Movie.objects.filter(visible=True,).order_by('-hot', '-showing', 'name')
        if self.kwargs.get('category', None):
            slugs = self.kwargs['category'].strip('/').split('/')
            self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slugs[-1])
            category_ids = [c.id for c in self.category.get_child_categories()]
            category_ids.append(self.category.id)
            qs = qs.filter(categories__in=category_ids)
        if self.kwargs.get('venue', None):
            self.venue = get_object_or_404(Venue, slug=self.kwargs['venue'])
            venue_ids = [v.id for v in Venue.objects.filter(parent=self.venue)]
            venue_ids.append(self.venue.id)
            qs = qs.filter(shows__venue__in=venue_ids)
        if self.kwargs.get('shortcut', None):
            today = datetime.date.today()
            shortcut = self.kwargs['shortcut']
            if shortcut == 'now-showing':
                qs = qs.filter(shows__starts__gte=today,)
            elif shortcut == 'today':
                qs = qs.filter(shows__starts__exact=today)
            elif shortcut == 'tomorrow':
                qs = qs.filter(shows__starts__exact=today + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
            elif shortcut == 'this-weekend': #Friday - Sunday
                days = 4 - today.weekday()
                starts = today + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
                ends = starts + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
                qs = qs.filter(shows__starts__range=(starts, ends))
            elif shortcut == 'tickets':
                qs = qs.filter(
                    shows__starts__gte=today,
                    shows__venue__name__icontains='imax',
                    visible=True
                )

        if self.kwargs.get('date', None):
            d = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.kwargs['date'], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            self.date = d
            qs = qs.filter(shows__starts__exact=d)
        return qs.distinct()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MovieList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        today = datetime.date.today()
        #context['categories'] = Category.objects.filter(parent__slug='movies', visible=True,)
        context['venues'] = Venue.objects.filter(show__starts__gte=today, parent=None, visible=True,).distinct()
        context['category'] = self.category
        context['venue'] = self.venue
        context['date'] = self.date
        context['dates'] = _get_movie_dates()
        context['now_showing'] = _get_now_showing()
        context['nos'] = len(self.slug_level)

        return context

class MovieDetail(StatsDetailView):
    model = Movie
    context_object_name = 'movie'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MovieDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        today = datetime.date.today()
        #context['categories'] = Category.objects.filter(parent__slug='movies', visible=True,)
        context['venues'] = Venue.objects.filter(show__starts__gte=today, parent=None, visible=True,).distinct()
        context['dates'] = _get_movie_dates()
        context['now_showing'] = _get_now_showing()
        return context


def buy_movie(req, slug):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, slug=slug)
    url = 'http://rdtickets.buymore.co.ke/api/buy?movie=%d' % movie.pk
    return render_to_response(
        'movies/movie_buy.html',
        locals(),
        RequestContext(req, {})
    )

def refresh_buy_more(req):

    movies = {}
    venues = {}
    shows = Show.objects.filter(starts__gte=datetime.date.today())

    for show in shows:
        movies[show.movie.pk] = show.movie
        venues[show.venue.pk] = show.venue

    for movie in movies:
        tasks.post_movie_to_buymore(movies[movie])

    for venue in venues:
        tasks.post_venue_to_buymore(venues[venue])

    for show in shows:
        tasks.post_show_to_buymore(show)

    return HttpResponse('synced')
```

There's no reference to a template from what I can find any assistance in figuring out where the template is will be appreciated.

Comment: Check your **urls.py**...it's possible the template name is being passed to the `as_view()` method there...although that's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects) explains how the view determines which template to use:

> That’s all the Python code we need to write. We still need to write a template, however. We could explicitly tell the view which template to use by adding a `template_name` attribute to the view, but in the absence of an explicit template Django will infer one from the object’s name. In this case, the inferred template will be `"books/publisher_list.html"` – the “books” part comes from the name of the app that defines the model, while the “publisher” bit is just the lowercased version of the model’s name.

So in your case, if you do not set `template_name`, the default template will be `movies/movie_list.html`.